# If I do get two static ips, can I get them through the same PPPoe connection (one cable)?

Tags: networking, router, ip-address, static-ip

I have a residential connection with one static IP currently.

I am really curious about, if it is possible to get one more Static IP with one cable, which is connected to my router's WAN port. Will it be possible to use two static IPs on the same broadband cable? Or do I need two separate connections to each of them respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes, its very possible in theory" but totally depends on your provider as to whether/how it can be implemented.  Your first problem is likely to be the "residential connection" bit - In my experience "residential connection" means cheap but mass market - which means its a lot harder to get something like that on a residential connection - primarily because of price/policy.

PPP is a Point to point connection, meaning that a PPP connection can typically only have a single static IP address associated with it - however it is common to route additional IP addresses across the PPP connection.   While it is possible to route individual IP addresses its a more common to route a subnet of IP's.   In this way the router can get 1 IP address associated with the PPP connection and then devices behind the router can be assigned static IP addresses, or the router can bind additional interfaces on virtual/LAN interfaces and do Source based NAT or similar.

I've never seen or heard of it, but I posit that it is plausible to also run 2 PPPoE connections from a single device/physical connections (with different credentials for the PPPoE accounts) and assign them different static IP addresses.  I imagine that this would be uncommon due to limited router support and technical difficulties with source based routing (but it is technically doable on a router which runs dd-wrt for example)

Another way to achieve this - which is slightly out of scope of what you asked, but if money is important and you want to do it over a residential connection - would be to keep the existing connection and get a VPN with a static IP (google it - they are quite common).  In this way you would be able to have the default static for your router, and run the VPN from a device behind your router to give it a different static IP - without your ISP hitting you up for more money - this way is simpler to - but at the cost of slightly lower efficiency for the second connection.